# How to Define nested Collection items in Hive

Tags: nested, hive

I am trying to create a hive table with nested Collection items. Suppose I have an array of struct.

```
    CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(
    record array<struct<col1:string,col2:string>>
    )row format delimited
    fields terminated by ','
    collection items terminated by '|';
```

First level, the separator ',' will override the default delimiter '^A'.

Second level, the separator '|' will override the default second level delimiter '^B' to separate out the outer most structure (i.e. Array).

Third level hive will use the default third level delimiter '^C' as the separator for the  Struct

Now my question is how can I define a separator for the second level (i.e. Struct), because '^C' character is hard to read as well as to generate.

Is there any way to explicitly define the separator instead of ^C ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(
id BIGINT,
record array<struct<col1:string,col2:string>>
)row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '|'
map keys terminated by ':';
```

Now you data in text file will look like this:

```
1345653,110909316904:1341894546|221065796761:1341887508
```

You can then query it like :

```
select record.col1 from SAMPLE;
```

Comment: great answer! can you please also suggest how to do this for map data? for instance i have a map<string,string> column in my hive table and i want to create a csv file to load data into my table. How should the map data look like in csv?