# Load data from text file in hive table for Nested records having complex data types

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to load bulk data from a text file in a hive table with schema mentioned below.

```
 {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "logs",
        "namespace": "com.xx.a.log",
        "fields": [{
            "name": "request_id",
            "type": ["null", "string"]
        }, 
        {
            "name": "results",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "result",
                    "fields": [{
                        "name": "d_type",
                        "type": ["null", "string"],
                        "default": null
                    }, {
                        "name": "p_type",
                        "type": ["null", "string"]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }, {
            "name": "filtered_c",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": "string"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "filtered_rejected",
            "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": "int"
            }
        }]
    }
```

**Created table query:**

```
create table log_table(
request_id  string  ,
results array<struct<d_type:string,p_type:string>>  ,
filtered_c  array<string> ,
filtered_rejected map<string,int> 

) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' collection items terminated by '|' map keys terminated by ':' stored as textfile
TBLPROPERTIES("serialization.null.format"="NULL");
```

But i am unable to get a proper delimiter for nested record elements inside an array.

If i use ',' to to separate child entries of results(nested) elements then only one entry is taken for inner object. rest is spilled over to parent level columns.

But if i use '|' as delimenter for inner column of row element then multiple objects of result gets created with only first entry initialized and rest as null.

Please suggest any query params and criteria if i am missing or please suggest any alternate way to solve this problem

Comment: Why a text file?!? Your input stinks of an AVRO source, so just use the AVRO SerDe...

Comment: If you insist on using a Text format, then try `:` as separator for fields in the embedded Struct, because it's not specific to "maps" -- and note that the Text SerDe supports only 2 levels of embedding; you can't define an Array-of-Structs-containing-Structs for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011252/how-to-define-nested-collection-items-in-hive

Comment: Yes it worked and : is working as field level delimiter inside a struct which is working as <K,V> separator in case of maps. and | worked as array element level delimiter. 
Thanks